# UITextField textColor reverts after resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have a UIButton that controls the textColor of a UITextField, and I have found that when I call resignFirstResponder on the UITextField, any changes to the textColor made while the text field was first responder are lost, and the color is reverted to the state before becomeFirstResponder. The behavior I am looking for is that the textColor should remain as whatever is chosen while the text field is first responder.

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 120.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 70.0f)];
    self.tf.delegate = self;
    self.tf.text = @"black";
    self.tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:48.0f];
    self.tf.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tf];
    self.tf.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 220.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20.0f)];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [b setTitle:@"Change color" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
}

- (void)changeColor:(UIButton *)button {
    if ([self.tf.textColor isEqual:[UIColor blackColor]]) {
        self.tf.text = @"red";
        self.tf.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.tf.text = @"black";
        self.tf.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

More specifically, the behavior is produced by the following actions:

1. UITextField *tf initially black.
2. Tap tf to becomeFirstResponder.
3. Tap UIButton *b, tf.textColor changes to red (text also changes to @"red", although this is not necessary).
4. Tap keyboard Return to resignFirstResponder, tf.textColor reverts back to black (text stays as @"red").

Analogously, if the initial textColor is red, the textField reverts back to red.

I've created an example project with only the features necessary to produce this behavior (available [here](https://github.com/cbosborn/CBOTextFieldColorRevert)). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround, you can just store the selected color on a property when the button is pressed and do this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    textField.textColor = self.selectedColor;
    return YES;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, a better place to put this workaround seems to be in `textFieldDidEndEditing` because it handles the case of jumping between fields:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.textColor = self.selectedColor;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried it myself before posting using your sample code and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it does work. I'll have to check why my initial attempt in my actual larger project didn't. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: In the case of my larger project, there is a scenario in which resignFirstResponder is called as firstResponder is passed to a different text field, and hence the keyboard is never dismissed, and the textFieldShouldReturn: delegate method is never called. Instead, using textFieldDidEndEditing: does the trick. Perhaps this is the more general solution.

Comment: Thank god for this! My text fields started doing this out of nowhere and I had no idea and still don't know why. This fixed it though, thanks!